# Android view enabled and focusable interaction

Tags: android, android-view

Does setting e.g. an EditText as disabled mean the view cannot take focus?  If I later re-enable the view, do my previous focus settings become applicable again?

Essentially, I am wondering if the two focus lines are necessary:

```
@Override
public void setEnabled(boolean enable) {
    super.setEnabled(enable);

    // Manually set nested view enabled state
    _myInnerView.setEnabled(enable);
    _myInnerView.setFocusable(enable);
    _myInnerView.setFocusableInTouchMode(enable);
}
```

Comment: I have, and they seem unnecessary, but I could've missed a case where they were actually needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
getWindow().getCurrentFocus();
```

to find out which view has the focus. With this just try how it goes in your specific Activity.